# Numerical Integration in Hexagonal Region

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a humongous function as shown in this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FC0WLUjkN6zle_aeKfW0pN1JEKo02ss1/view?usp=sharing) (I reached the limit of characters)
I want to integrate this function over the region of 3D hexagonal as shown in the figure,
[image]

Here, the limit of $k_x \in (\frac{-4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}},\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$, $k_y\in(\frac{-2\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3})$ and $k_z \in (\frac{-\pi}{3},\frac{-\pi}{3})$. I integrated the function as using MonteCarlo method as plot as function of $ef$,

```
Transpose[{Range[-4, 4, 0.1], 
 ParallelTable[
  NIntegrate[
  f[kx, ky, kz, ef], {kx, (-4 \[Pi])/(3 Sqrt[3] a), (4 \[Pi])/(
  3 Sqrt[3] a)}, {ky, (-2 \[Pi])/(3 a), (2 \[Pi])/(
  3 a)}, {kz, -\[Pi]/c, \[Pi]/c}, 
  Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"], {ef, -4, 4, 0.1}]}]]
```

The problem is I am not integrating over the region of the 3D hexagon but over the cuboid of the limits mentioned above. This will slightly overestimate the values of integration. The region integration of Mathematica doesn't allow the Monte-Carlo method and without the Montecarlo method, it is impossible to integrate accurately. I have also tried the following integration method
$$\int_{Hexagon}dkx\ dky\ dkz\ f[kx,ky,kz,ef] = \int_{-2\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}dkx \int_{-2\pi/\sqrt{3}}^{2\pi/\sqrt{3}}dky \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}dkz + \int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3}dkx \int_{\sqrt{3}kx-4\pi/\sqrt{3}}^{-\sqrt{3}kx+4\pi/\sqrt{3}}dky \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}dkz + \int_{-4\pi/3}^{-2\pi/3}dkx \int_{-\sqrt{3}kx-4\pi/\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}kx+4\pi/\sqrt{3}}dky \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}dkz$$

But this method takes an exponentially long time. Can someone tell me any method I can integrate with this region?

Comment: How about subtracting from the cuboid result, integration of the four wedge-shape regions?

Comment: @josh Yes, my next idea was to do that. But as I said at the end of the question, doing that kind of integration takes a lot of time. But since these residual regions are small, in principle it should be feasible. I haven't performed the calculations, I will update how it goes.

Comment: @josh Yeah it's no good. The residual part is the same as the second and third terms of my last equation. So it takes a lots of time